# Two columns of data need to be saved as an excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have two columns of data, x and y values, and need to save the file as an excel file to be opened in excel. Are there any modules that can help me with this?

The format needs to be xls

The data looks as follows:

```
  4.20985      17.1047
  4.82755      16.4046
  3.17238      12.1246
  4.50796      18.0955
  6.04241      21.1016
  4.62863      16.4974
  4.32245      14.6536
  6.48382      19.7664
  5.66514      20.1288
  6.11072      22.6859
  5.55167      15.7504
```

Comment: Please be more specific: show what kind of data do you need to write to excel, what format do you need: `xls`, `xlsx` or may be just `csv`?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Yes. If you're on windows, you'll need to install ``http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/`` This is the library that lets me query Outlook from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you'd be good with creating a `csv` file, but since you've asked about `xls`, here's an example using [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) module:

```
import xlwt

data = """
  4.20985      17.1047
  4.82755      16.4046
  3.17238      12.1246
  4.50796      18.0955
  6.04241      21.1016
  4.62863      16.4974
  4.32245      14.6536
  6.48382      19.7664
  5.66514      20.1288
  6.11072      22.6859
  5.55167      15.7504
"""

# prepare two-dimensional list
data = [map(float, item.split()) for item in data.split('\n') if item]

# create workbook and add sheet
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('Test')

# loop over two-dimensional list and write data
for index, (value1, value2) in enumerate(data):
    sheet.write(index, 0, value1)
    sheet.write(index, 1, value2)

# save a workbook
workbook.save('test.xls')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this allowed me to open it up in excel and create a scatter plot from data. thank you very much!